# Select column by drag and drop dynamically in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am creating a report using SSRS report server. I want to allow the user to create customized reports by selecting columns by drag and drop and generate report instantly.

Right now i am using report builder to create report. But user can only view the reports or can select the columns which I have provided in the report.

But i want to allow the user to create his own report.

1. Is there any way to do this?
2. Is it possible in SSRS to allow drag and drop in a published report?

Comment: Not by drag and drop but you can allow users to show/hide columns. Right click on a tablix column / `column visibility` / `Display can be toggled by this report item.`

Comment: You should look into PowerPivot. It is much more interactive than report builder. The user just needs to have Excel.

Comment: I agree with Mike D.  Allowing the user to create their own report is what Excel is for, not SSRS.

Comment: If you want users to create their own reports I would recommend PowerPivot like Mike D suggested. It is easier to learn and more interactive and provides a great UI.

Comment: can I use PowerPivot in web application

Answer (score -2):

**Welcome

```js
function wow(){
alert('Nag hintay kaba? sorry walana, its a prank!!!!');
}
```

```css
body{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1 onclick='wow()'><a href=''>Drag me</a></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**